# Build single directive to perform both Structural & Attribute behaviour?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to build an Angular Directive where I want to achieve following things based on some config input values

1. Add element in DOM  based on input values. (Just like ngIf)
2. Add some styling to element if its rendered
3. Add some attribute properties like `disabled` to element

As per my little bit knowledge and understanding of Angular, we can achieve 1st requirement using [Structural Directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html). Where as for 2nd & 3rd requirement we need to create [Attribute Directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html). Here is my implementation for both directives

```
import { SomeService } from './some.service';
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[structuralBehaviour]' })
export class StructuralBehaviourDirective {

    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private someService: SomeService) { }

    @Input() set structuralBehaviour(config: any) {

        // 1st Condition
        // Conditional Stamentents using config and somService
        // For the purpose to decide whether to add template in
        // DOM or not
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);

   }
}
```

Here is Attribute Directive

```
import { SomeService } from './some.service';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[attributeBehaviour]' })
export class AttributeBehaviourDirective {

    constructor(private _renderer: Renderer, private _el: ElementRef,
    private someService: SomeService) { }

    @Input() set attributeBehaviour(config: any) {

        // 2nd Condition
        // Conditional Stamentents using config and someService
        // For the purpose to set style visibility property to hidden
        this._el.nativeElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        // 3rd Condition
        // Conditional Stamentents using config and someService
        // For the purpose to add disabled attribute
        this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._el.nativeElement, 'disabled, true);

    }
}
```

Currently, I am using above directives like follows which works fine for me

```
<button *structuralBehaviour="config" [attributeBehaviour]="config"
 class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

What I am looking out here is answer to question, Is it possible to merge both of above directive together and build single directive out of it so that I can use them something like this

```
<button *singleBehaviour="config" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

Comment: Ajax, are you using jQuery, or can you include it in your project? jQuery could make quick work of your problems.

Comment: Nope, I am not using JQuery, trying to achieve it with Angular Typescript code only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView` returns `EmbeddedViewRef` that contains `rootNodes`. You can use it to implement your behaviour

```
@Directive({ selector: '[singleBehaviour]' })
export class SingleBehaviourDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private _renderer: Renderer2,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() set singleBehaviour(config: any) {
    let view = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    let rootElem = view.rootNodes[0];
    if(rootElem) {
      rootElem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      this._renderer.setProperty(rootElem, 'disabled', true);
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/46pO069E3Px85unpbdwV?p=preview)**